# How to create a background-running Cocoa application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How do I create a Cocoa app that runs in the background (not in the dock, and not in the menu bar either; just in the background).

Does the app need admin privileges? I hope not. Actually it shouldn't, because it's enough that the app runs in the background *for that user only*, i.e. not for all users.

And I guess I can make it "launch when log-in" by just adding it to the user's Account Preferences, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your Info.plist set [LSBackgroundOnly](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-109268) to 1.

Answer (score 12):

In your Info.plist, set [LSUIElement](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-108256) to the string “1”.

The main difference is that a UI-element agent can have a UI (order in a window). A background-only app should be completely faceless; whatever UI it has should exist in a separate application or preference pane.

Comment: make it `bool` `YES` not `string` `"1"`

Comment: Interesting that it is now documented as being a Boolean: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/lsuielement?language=objc The old documentation was very clear that it was meant to be a *string* that could be set to "1": https://web.archive.org/web/20141004073224/https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-108256 Not sure if the facts changed, the old docs were wrong, or the new docs are wrong (though string "1" definitely works).